# No R, qual a melhor maneira de selecionar conjuntos das listas internas dentro de uma lista de listas?

Tags: r, lista

Tenho uma lista de listas como a que segue:

```
lista <- list(num = list(1:10, 11:20, 21:30),
              chr = list(letters[1:13], letters[14:26], LETTERS[1:13]))
```

Gostaria de transformá-la em um `data.frame`, mas para isso as duas listas internas teriam de ter o mesmo tamanho. Para alcançar este objetivo, gostaria selecionar um conjunto com apenas os 10 primeiros elementos de cada lista interna (perder algumas observações da lista que será cortada não será um problema).

Consegui realizar esta tarefa por meio de uma função não muito elegante (com loop, postada abaixo) e fiquei imaginando se não há formas mais eficientes de fazer isso.

Como temos pouca documentação sobre `R` em português, achei razoável perguntar: no `R`, qual a melhor maneira de selecionar conjuntos das listas internas dentro de uma lista de listas?

Comment: Não entendi porque responder a tua própria pergunta. Não seria mais interessante colocar o código [deste link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165892/49033) no teu post original? Pois imagine se alguém responde a tua pergunta e esta resposta recebe votos. Ela vai ficar à frente da tua resposta, descontextualizando a tua dúvida. Isto não é interessante para quem vier fazer pesquisas no SO futuramente.

Comment: Esta é uma opção dada pelo StackOverflow. Entendo sua preocupação, mas minha resposta é um possível resposta à pergunta. Caso outra pessoa tenha outra solução ela pode postar abaixo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acho a forma a seguir mais concisa para fazer o que você precisa:

```
library(purrr) # para a função map
library(tidyr) # para a função unnest
library(dplyr) # para a função as_data_frame
map(lista, ~map(.x, ~.x[1:10])) %>%
  as_data_frame() %>%
  unnest()
```

O resultado é esse:

```
# A tibble: 30 × 2
     num   chr
   <int> <chr>
1      1     a
2      2     b
3      3     c
4      4     d
5      5     e
6      6     f
7      7     g
8      8     h
9      9     i
10    10     j
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Uma outra forma, que também fica legal é:

```
lista %>%
  as_data_frame() %>%
  mutate(chr = map(chr, ~.x[1:10])) %>%
  unnest()
```

`list columns`, ou seja, colunas de data.frames que são listas estão sendo bastante utilizadas e popularizadas pelo Hadley Wickham. Veja aqui no [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1).

No exemplo com `list columns` só modifiquei a coluna chr, mas você poderia modificar todas as colunas usando:

```
lista %>%
  as_data_frame() %>%
  mutate_all(funs(map(., ~.x[1:10]))) %>%
  unnest()
```

**Complementando o Benchmark do Tomás**

```
> lista <- list(
+   num = lapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:100, 20)),
+   chr = lapply(1:10, function(x) sample(letters, 20))
+ )
> microbenchmark(
+   solucao_tomas = {as.data.frame(sapply(lapply(lista, pegar_elem, 1:10), unlist))},
+   solucao_daniel = {unnest(as_data_frame(map(lista, ~map(.x, ~.x[1:10]))))}
+ )
Unit: microseconds
           expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
  solucao_tomas  419.026  439.375  466.7568  454.947  476.889  695.780   100
 solucao_daniel 2456.108 2559.625 2745.8009 2680.130 2836.733 4466.647   100
> lista <- list(
+   num = lapply(1:1000, function(x) sample(1:100, 20)),
+   chr = lapply(1:1000, function(x) sample(letters, 20))
+ )
> microbenchmark(
+   solucao_tomas = {as.data.frame(sapply(lapply(lista, pegar_elem, 1:10), unlist))},
+   solucao_daniel = {unnest(as_data_frame(map(lista, ~map(.x, ~.x[1:10]))))}
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  solucao_tomas 13.559905 14.15854 14.64829 14.56517 14.83060 16.89264   100
 solucao_daniel  9.871144 10.27053 11.07952 10.80652 11.29402 19.82793   100
> lista <- list(
+   num = lapply(1:10000, function(x) sample(1:100, 20)),
+   chr = lapply(1:10000, function(x) sample(letters, 20))
+ )
> microbenchmark(
+   solucao_tomas = {as.data.frame(sapply(lapply(lista, pegar_elem, 1:10), unlist))},
+   solucao_daniel = {unnest(as_data_frame(map(lista, ~map(.x, ~.x[1:10]))))}
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
  solucao_tomas 156.63202 171.06855 195.3683 180.86325 227.1462 271.7314   100
 solucao_daniel  80.93934  91.22597 100.5079  96.73947 104.7544 154.6254   100
```

Ou seja, quando a lista é pequena a solução do Tomás usando `for` é mais eficiente, no entanto a diferença aí está na casa de microsegundos. (eficiência não é muito importante quando os objetos são pequenos). Quando os objetos começam a crescer, a solução usando `purrr`, `dplyr` e `tidyr` passa a ser mais eficiente. Com listas de tamanho 10.000 ela chega a ser 2x mais rápida. Essa solução é eficiente quando é necessário, isto é, quando o tamanho dos objetos cresce.

Answer (score 2):

```
pegar_elem <- function(x, vetor){
  xx <- x
  for (i in seq_along(xx)) {
    xx[[i]] <- xx[[i]][vetor]
  }
  return(xx)
}

lista2 <- lapply(lista, pegar_elem, 1:10)
as.data.frame(sapply(lista2, unlist))
```

**EDITADO**

Apesar de as respostas do [Daniel Falbel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165945/43953) serem mais elegantes, registro:

```
microbenchmark({as.data.frame(sapply(lapply(lista, pegar_elem, 1:10), unlist))},
               {map(lista, ~map(.x, ~.x[1:10])) %>% as_data_frame() %>% unnest()},
               {lista %>% as_data_frame() %>% mutate(chr = map(chr, ~.x[1:10])) %>% unnest()})

  min        lq       mean     median        uq      max   neval
  353.818  367.506  395.5651  395.2225  413.3585  561.525   100
 3735.283 3774.977 3929.1722 3811.0775 3879.1725 6091.565   100
 4090.128 4157.026 4313.8627 4179.2685 4267.0385 6863.874   100
```

Comment: Esse becnchmark muda dependendo do tamanho das listas. Quando cada lista de dentro tem tamanho 1000, a minha solução passa a ser mais rápida.